# What does the word "residents" in this sentence refer to?

Tags: word-meaning

**[SOURCE](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/15/nyregion/bronx-gang-violence-murders.html)**  (N. Y. Times)

I'm not sure what the word "residents" mean in this sentence.

> The brutality of the ambush gave even the most hardened **residents** and detectives pause.

I assumed at first it means people who live nearby, but now I wonder if means doctors. The word is in parallel with "detectives", and the word "resident" has a meaning in the US of "a doctor who is training in a hospital".

What does the word "residents" in this sentence refer to exactly?

Comment: Can you add a bit more context? The meaning isn't entirely clear from that sentence alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your quote from *The New York Times* article [As Nationwide
Gangs Fracture, Bullets
Fly in New York](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/15/nyregion/bronx-gang-violence-murders.html?_r=0)

> residents

is used to mean "*people who live in an area*", in this case specifically the South Bronx where violence is not infrequent, and not medical personnel.